# Are there any reasonably-priced technology to measure any part of your body to help cut the pressure garment precisely

Tags: dermatology, measurement, burns, clothes, technology

I am not sure if this topic belongs here but could not find a more relevant stackexchange site.

My kid is receiving a  pressure garment treatment to recover from severe burn. However, cutting the pressure garment fabric precisely is a difficult task and some times measures are not accurate, resulting in delays in the treatment.

I wonder if there are any software that can scan your body and then tell you the measurements automatically in an accurate way. I appreciate any help!